# Automapper: CreateMap but for a property which is not initialized yet

Tags: automapper

How can I create a Map with Automapper when in the underlying destination type a property not yet has initialized?

Example:

```
public class UserAccount
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string,string> properties { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccountOtherType
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string Property1 {get;set; }
}

public static UserAccount CustomMap(UserAccountOtherType type2)
{
   AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UserAccount,UserAccountOtherType>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.properties["Property1", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src.Property1));

 return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<UserAccount,UserAccountOtherType>(type2);

}
```

When I try to execute this code it fails because the Dictionary in UserAccount is not yet initialized. I cannot initialize the Object by myself because the UserAccount Class is a Datacontract of a WCF Serviceinterface. 
I have to create a Dicationary by myself and assign it to the property.

```
UserAccount b = new UserAccount();
Dictionary<string,string> properties = new Dictionary<string,string>();
b.properties = properties;
```

How can I solve this with Automapper? Or is my approach not senseful?

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of to do something like this is to write a class that implements `AutoMapper.IValueResolver`.  Then `opt.MapFrom...` becomes `opt.ResolveUsing....FromMember...`  Probably at that point your destination is the entire dictionary (I think if you leave out the `FromMember` you get the whole object into your resolver

in your implementation of `IValueResolver.Resolve`, try breaking into the debugger and checking out the `ResolutionContext` in `source.Context`, then once you have your dictionary built, return `source.New(myDictionary)`